# How to deal with the AJAX concurrent max?

Tags: javascript, ajax, express

**I am doing a autocomplete search bar.**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="text" >

<script>
    $("input").keyup(function(){
        let key = $("input").val();

        $.ajax({
            url: '/search',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: JSON.stringify({key}),
            success: function(data){
                console.log("SUCCESS")
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

When user input to the text box, I want to send each key when user type to the backend server to do the suggestion work. However, it will meet the 6 times AJAX concurrent maximum very soon. **So, how can I figure it out?**

Comment: Why do you need the autocomplete to do this instead of just throttling the requests?  Most of the search requests would probably be discarded as they would be out of date by the time the server returns. ...But .. you can try subdomains or you could batch the keys together if they occur within a time limit.  What have you tried?

Comment: @IanWilson My task is doing a "google search like" search bar. I think I can use AJAX to pass the keyword to server on time. My search database is small, searching is not a problem.

Comment: How long are your responses taking?  It sounds to me like the first issue is that they're too slow to respond.  If you haven't responded to the first request before 6 characters have been typed, then the response is probably too slow.  Then, you probably want a slight delay before sending so you group multiple characters typed quickly in succession rather than fire off a separate Ajax request for each.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't you want to a) cancel any existing request when a new one is made:

```
let inFlight;
$("input").keyup(function(){
    let key = $("input").val();
    if (inFlight) {
        inFlight.abort();
    }
    inFlight = $.ajax({
        url: '/search',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify({key}),
        success: function(data){
            console.log("SUCCESS")
        }
    });
});
```

and b) debounce the requests, so it doesn't try to autocomplete until they pause their typing (in this example, 500ms after the last keyup):

```
let inFlight;
let debounce;
$("input").keyup(function(){
    let key = $("input").val();
    if (inFlight) {
        inFlight.abort();
    }
    if (debounce) {
        clearTimeout(debounce);
    }
    debounce = setTimeout(() => {
        inFlight = $.ajax({
            url: '/search',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: JSON.stringify({key}),
            success: function(data){
                console.log("SUCCESS")
            }
        });
    }, 500);
});
```